# custom make install in Docker file

Tags: php, laravel, docker, makefile

Not able to run `make install` from docker file, not sure where I am going wrong.

Getting below error message when `docker-compose build` is run in ubuntu

```
Step 6/10 : RUN make install
 ---> Running in c8f67e8de3b5
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: 
       The command '/bin/sh -c make install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I have the below structure where server is **laravel** project and in root there is a **docker-compose.yml** file.

[image]

Below is the structure of **server** folder

[image]

**docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: api_server
    container_name: api_server
    build:
      context: ./server/release
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/app
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils zip unzip && \
    apt-get install -y nano && \
    apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpq-dev libpng-dev&& \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

COPY default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN make install

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/storage

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
```

**server/Makefile**

```
install:
    # some other commands
    composer install

refresh:
    # For testing
    php artisan migrate:refresh
    php artisan db:seed

make run:
    php artisan migrate:status
    php artisan serve
```

Basically if I comment `RUN make install` and `RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/storage` commands from **Dockerfile** it works. To test i'll get into the container and run the above 2 commands manually then it works by showing the default laravel page.

So I feel trying to run the above 2 commands from **Dockerfile** i guess source code isn't available at that point.

Comment: How does that Makefile get into the image?  Based on what you've shown, `/var/www/app` will be an empty directory when you `RUN make install`.

Comment: yes thats what i actually figured out..  so whats the solution for it @DavidMaze

Comment: @DavidMaze is there any other alternate way ?

Comment: Are [build-essentials](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/build-essential) installed?

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer yes i tried adding build-essentials apt package still same error

Comment: as @DavidMaze has mentioned working dir is empty. as suggested in docker image's how to use  
`FROM php:7.4-cli
 COPY . /usr/src/myapp
 WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp`  
now when makefile is in working dir  
`RUN make install`